# how to get data from an Android Activity?

Tags: android

I need Activity A to retrieve the string value from a textview in Activity B. The catch is I don't want Activity B to send the data, I just want Activity A to reach out and grab the data from B. I understand about Bundles and Intents, but the problem I'm having is that every time Activity B is accessed, it sends the bundled intent to A. I don't want that to happen, I just want Activity A to grab the string from Activity B's textview whenever Activity A is accessed. I'm using Android 2.2 and SDK 8.

Comment: You cannot simply grab information from another `Activity`.

Comment: This doesn't even make sense. Say you launch Activity B from Activity A. Activity B is above Activity A. You close Activity B, you're back to Activity A. If you're on Activity A, Activity B does not exist currently and thus there is no TextView or content on that TextView. Now perhaps you may have some other static data structure somewhere that Activity B can modify, then Activity A can grab that data at any time.

Comment: Thats not possible, Activity classes dont act as data classes do in desk top java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, your problem is that Activity A and Activity B are not talking so you need to access a certain data from A without involving B.

Imho you can solve this problem saving the data somewhere that is shared by both Activities.
You can use one of the options listed here in the Data Storage chapter:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

I would go with shared preferences if it's just a simple string.

That said, it's not really clear what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class A extends Activity {


   public static TextView textView = null;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

     textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);


}
}
```

public class B extends Activity {

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

                //Thats how you can get the data from Activity A UI Control
        //A.textView.getText().toString() 
     Log.i("Activity A TextView Data" , A.textView.getText().toString());


}
}
```

Comment: It will work when Activity A is in the stack and your current activity will be B.

Answer (score 0):

Save Activity B's textview string as persistent storage.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't assume any of the Views for Activity B are available when Activity A is active. In fact, Android could garbage-collect Activity B while it's in the background. Activities are not like "windows"; they're much more independent.

However, I'm pretty sure you can do this by implementing two *fragments*.